# How to fix GTsummary cox table

Tags: error-handling, gtsummary, cox-regression

I am receiving this error (after it was previously working) for my univariate cox modeling table. It appears to be trying to model "identifier" while identifier is the clustering variable. Is there a way I can code this differently? I appreciate your assistance.

````
        cox.model.data <- 
    tbl1 <- cox.model.data %>% 
      select(
        tstart,
        tstop,
        status,
        Site,
        job_cat)
        #TABLE 2 
    uvlm_table <- 
      tbl_uvregression(
        tbl1 %>%
          select( tstart,
                  tstop,
                  status,
                  Site,
                  job_cat
       ),
        method = coxph,
        y = Surv(tstart, tstop, status),
        method.args = list(cluster = identifier),
        formula = "{y} ~ {x} + strata(Site)",
        exponentiate = TRUE,
        pvalue_fun = ~style_pvalue(.x, digits=3)
      )
    Adding missing grouping variables: `identifier`
    x There was an error constructing model `coxph(formula = Surv(tstart, tstop, status) ~ identifier + strata(Site),      data = ., cluster = identifier)` See error below.
    Error in `mutate()`:
    i In argument: `model = map(...)`.
    Caused by error in `map()`:
    i In index: 1.
    Caused by error in `value[[3L]]()`:
    ! Error in agreg.fit(X, Y, istrat, offset, init, control, weights = weights, : exp overflow due to covariates

```[![enter image description here][1]][1]

 

           structure(list(identifier = c("HPB0002", "HPB0002", "HPB0002", 
    "HPB0002", "HPB0002", "HPB0002"), tstart = c(0, 8, 13, 20, 28, 
    35), tstop = c(8, 13, 20, 28, 35, 43), status = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0), Site = c("hnch", "hnch", "hnch", "hnch", "hnch", "hnch"
    ), job_cat = c("Nurse", "Nurse", "Nurse", "Nurse", "Nurse", "Nurse"
    )), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
    ))


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvQng.png
````

Comment: Please update your post with an example we can run on our machines? Aka a minimal reproducible example (reprex).

Comment: Unfortunately, I am unsure how to go about adding a R table, or csv to this question.

Comment: use `dput(yourdata)` and then copy the contents into your question, if the data are too large do `dput(head(yourdata))`

Comment: Thank you Mike, I was able to follow your instructions. Please see sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed:
Added "+ cluster(identifier)" to the function

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it solved the problem.